# ERROR(Save Error: duplicate Alias: Name) when using Day_Only

Tags: soql, opportunity, query, datetime, date

I'm using the following SOQL query to populate a custom controller for our sales team to view their opps on the opp tab landing page.  It works fine with CloseDate alone, but the field is returned as a datetime and I want a standard date; no time or timezone info necessary.  The problem is that when I add "DAY_ONLY", it the force.comIDE returns "Save error: duplicate alias: Name" stating the location as the start line for this query.  I've tried referencing both the account name and opportunity name in different manners, but I continue to receive this message.

Any idea what's causing this name error when Days_Only is used, but no error when referencing the field without field manipulation?

I've also tried using a Group By clause, and tried using Group By without the account fields in it (assuming that it considers them aggregations or functions), but neither of those worked in my experience.

```
[Select Opportunity_Reference__c, 
        Account.Name, 
        Account.BillingState, 
        Name,
        DAY_ONLY(convertTimezone(CloseDate)), 
        Models__c, 
        Probability, 
        StageName 
     from Opportunity
     where OwnerId = :current_user_id
     ORDER by Opp_Ref__c desc
]
```

Comment: I've figured out that the system wants me to alias one of my names, so I went with ""Account.Name account, Account.BillingState...".  The error then changes to "Save error: only datetime fields support: DAY_ONLY".  This still doesn't make sense as the field is listed as Date, but displays on our custom page it displays as DateTime.

Comment: You don't by any chance have a custom datetime field that you're using as close date instead?

Comment: I've gotten the CloseDate field to show up properly on our page without date manipulation (had to use apex:output**Field** as opposed to apex:output**Text**), but I still have no idea why the query requires aliasing when using the aggregate formula and doesn't require it without.